# HTML button tag with ascii text for left and right arrows causes square vs round buttons

Tags: html, button, ascii

Why do I get a square button using ascii code for Black Left-Pointing Triangle, but a round button using ascii code for Black Right-Pointing Triangle?

`<button>&#9664</button>
 <button>&#9654</button>`

https://jsfiddle.net/3cpus6gh/

As viewed in Chrome v49 and Safari v5.1.1 on Mac:

[square vs round buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa4Bv.png)

Comment: So this jsfiddle works perfectly for me, I am using Chromium (Linux Chrome)

Comment: This jsfiddle too works for me under Safari. Please provide details about your testing browser or a screenshot.